# Python Pandas - Interpolation with fixed value

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have a pandas series with the following values

`[np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 2, np.nan]`

What is the most efficient way fill the nan value with 0 in the middle. so we have

`[np.nan, np.nan, 1, 0, 2, np.nan]`

In other word, how to we do interpolation with a fixed value, or a `.fillna` operation but ignore the `nan` at the beginning and end of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current solution, I am using

```
def interpolate_with_fixed(s, value=0):
    i = s.first_valid_index()
    j = s.last_valid_index()
    s.loc[i:j].fillna(value, inplace=True)
    return s
```

Comment: This my hackish solution. Would like to know if there is a more elegent solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is quite idiomatic.
Here is an alternative solution:

```
In [355]: s.loc[s.notnull().idxmax() : s[::-1].notnull().idxmax()].fillna(0, inplace=True)

In [356]: s
Out[356]:
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    0.0
4    2.0
5    NaN
dtype: float64
```